# How to show cells in common

Tags: excel

Im trying to use filter for show commons cells.
In excel, i have 2 columns and theirs values:

```
col1, col2
A,D1
A,D2
A,D3
B,D1
B,D3
C,D1
```

How to show only A and B for D1 and D3 filters?

====== edit 2016-06-12 =====
Comment to Scott:

Filtering to D1 and D2, the resul is showed. But I want to show only A and B

[image: Filtering to D1 and D2, the resul is showed. But I want to show only A and B.]

See:

I want the intersection.

[image]

Comment: Both the [filter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-data-in-an-Excel-table-7d8e9739-2898-4bfe-9d0f-c6204e6e5c8a) and [advanced filter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-4c9222fe-8529-4cd7-a898-3f16abdff32b) will do this.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned above by @ScottCraner, the simple filter is one way to do this.

Data ► Sort and Filter ► Filter

- At the `col1` dropdown select the `A` and the `B`
- At the `col2` dropdown select the `D1` and the `D3`

Results:

[image]

For the Advanced filter, it is simpler to use formulas, so you can `AND` the two `OR`'s.  (You could use named columns, but you would have to list every possible combination; easy with just the two that you have, but with more than two choices, it would become ungainly to maintain). See below for an example of useable formulas using an array constant to delineate the choices:

- The shown formulas in row 3 are actually in row 2.

[image]

[image]